# Jira upgrade to 7.1 not running on Windows Server

Tags: jira

When jira is successfully upgraded to 7.1 it suddenly stopped working. Also, running jira service not solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually update `dbconfig.xml` for now. They are currently working to fix this.

*Follow these steps to run jira again:*

1- Go *C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA* and open **dbconfig.xml**

2- Find `</jdbc-datasource>`

3- Add `<validation-query>select 1</validation-query>` to before `</jdbc-datasource>`

4- **Stop Jira** server from Task manager and **Run Jira** service again.

Should look like this:
[image]